# How can i download a file on a button's onClick event in C#?

Tags: c#, download, windows-forms-designer

Im trying to download a file on my button's onClick event in C# anyone got any info on this?

Ok so to the people who wanted me to be a litle more specific im working in visual studio 2015 windows forms c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, question is too broad (Not specified is that desktop or Web application) . Lets suggest that you mean Winforms, then quick answer is DownloadFileAsync ( Async in order to keep UI interactive for user):

```
  private void Download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
      {
         wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
         wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri("http://url"),
          "Result location");
      }
   }
```

It`s a good idea to have a progress bar:

```
   void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender,  DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks m8 this worked perfectly nice touch with the progress bar too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVC then you can try the following code it is working for me :

```
#region Download File ==>
        public ActionResult downloadfile(string Filename, string MIMEType)
        {
            try
            {
                string file_name = "/Files/EvidenceUploads/" + Filename;
                string contentType = "";
                //Get the physical path to the file.
                string FilePath = Server.MapPath(file_name);

                string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file_name);

                contentType = MIMEType;

                //Set the appropriate ContentType.
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + (new FileInfo(file_name)).Name);

                //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
                Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
                Response.End();
                return View(FilePath);
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.End();
                return View();
                //To Do
            }

        }
        #endregion
```

If you are not using MVC please refer following code:

```
#region Download File ==>
        public void downloadfile(string Filename, string MIMEType)
        {
            try
            {
                string file_name = "/Files/EvidenceUploads/" + Filename;
                string contentType = "";
                //Get the physical path to the file.
                string FilePath = Server.MapPath(file_name);

                string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file_name);

                contentType = MIMEType;

                //Set the appropriate ContentType.
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + (new FileInfo(file_name)).Name);

                //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
                Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
                Response.End();

            }
            catch
            {
                Response.End();

                //To Do
            }

        }
        #endregion
```

Hope its help to you.

Comment: This looks like it assumes OP is using MVC, which there was no indication of

Comment: you are right the code is for MVC with ActionResult and return View but in  try block, there is file downloading code which is understandable for ASP.net programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET MVC I used the following within a controller to return a file from the content/Audiofile folder.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// The download action returns the file as a File download.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="filename"></param>
 /// <returns></returns>
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public FilePathResult Download(String filename)
 {
    String myfile = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/audiofiles/"), filename);
    return File(myfile, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
 }
```